# GPUImage detect when processing is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage to filter videos and I am making Filter picker and every time  the user selects a filter it processes the video the problem is if they pick a filter while its still processing the app crashes. So I need a way to detect when the processing is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GPUImageMovie, check the progress value to determine if a process is currently running.  A value in-between 0.0 and 1.0 would mean that the movie is being processed.

Here is a possible implementation: If a process request is received during processing, record the request (using an NSArray for example) and create a NSTimer that repeatedly checks the progress of the movie currently processing.  Once the progress = 1.0, invalidate the timer and start the next process.

Comment: Right but how do you detect when the processing is finished to set the bool back to NO?

Comment: Brad Larson could certainly give you the best answer to this but if you are using a GPUImageMovie as your video then I believe calling either cancelProcessing or endProcessing before you call startProcessing again may help.

Comment: The problem with using cancelProcessing and endProcessing is that it ends the processing before it is finished.